# What is grammar of strange form of やめる verb like "やめたくなったら"?

Tags: verbs, conjugations

I found the word やめたくなったら. I think it's a conditional past form of やめる. Or maybe it's やめた conjugated with なったら (conditional form of なる). But the く in the middle distracts me: I can't find this form in a dictionary. Can you help me to find some grammar for that? 
And all I can guess for translation is only like "if want to stop".

Comment: たい conjugates to たく

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60462/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16130/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Unfortunately, this is one of those questions where it is easy to find the answer only if you know what to look for (i.e. if you already know the answer).

Comment: ^ So that's why I'm letting you know! ^o^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

やめたく is not the た-form, it is based on やめたい ('I want to stop'). なる requires a construction either with に (for nouns and な-adjectives) or -く (the adverb based on い-adjectives).